# why cant i echo imap headers subject line? php

Tags: php, imap

Using the following class:

```
class Email_reader {

        // imap server connection
        public $conn;

        // inbox storage and inbox message count
        private $inbox;
        private $msg_cnt;

        // email login credentials
        private $server = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
        private $user   = 'admin@xxxxxxxxx.com';
        private $pass   = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        private $port   = 143; // adjust according to server settings

        // connect to the server and get the inbox emails
        function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
            $this->inbox();
        }

        // close the server connection
        function close() {
            $this->inbox = array();
            $this->msg_cnt = 0;

            imap_close($this->conn);
        }

        // open the server connection
        // the imap_open function parameters will need to be changed for the particular server
        // these are laid out to connect to a Dreamhost IMAP server
        function connect() {
            $this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.'/notls}', $this->user, $this->pass);
        }

        // move the message to a new folder
        function move($msg_index, $folder='INBOX.Processed') {
            // move on server
            imap_mail_move($this->conn, $msg_index, $folder);
            imap_expunge($this->conn);

            // re-read the inbox
            $this->inbox();
        }

        // get a specific message (1 = first email, 2 = second email, etc.)
        function get($msg_index=NULL) {
            if (count($this->inbox) <= 0) {
                return array();
            }
            elseif ( ! is_null($msg_index) && isset($this->inbox[$msg_index])) {
                return $this->inbox[$msg_index];
            }

            return $this->inbox[0];
        }

        // read the inbox
        function inbox() {
            $this->msg_cnt = imap_num_msg($this->conn);

            $in = array();
            for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_cnt; $i++) {
                $in[] = array(
                    'index'     => $i,
                    'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
                    'body'      => imap_body($this->conn, $i),
                    'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
                );
            }

            $this->inbox = $in;
        }

    }
```

And the following usage code:

```
$email = new Email_reader();
$msg = $email->get(1);
echo "message body is [".$msg['body']."]<br />"; //prints body //good
echo "message index is [".$msg['index']."]<br />"; //prints "2" //good
echo "message subject is [".$msg['header']->Subject."]<br />"; //prints strangness
echo "message toaddress is [".$msg['header']->toaddress."]<br />"; //prints strangeness
```

the attempt to print subject line prints "=?utf-8?B?TWljcm9zb2Z0IE9mZmljZSBPdXRsb29rIFRlc3QgTWVzc2FnZQ==?="
and the toaddress also something similar.

I looked at some other examples online but i dont see anything different that they do than what im doing.

Comment: These are called Encoded Words. MIME does not allow headers to carry 8 bit data, so they're encoded. I don't know the functions to decode them in PHP, but in that case, it's a base64 (B) of a utf-8 encoding of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode the RFC 2047 encoding of the Unicode data. Check the [`imap_utf8`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php) function.